# Overriding `Comparison method violates its general contract` exception

Tags: scala, comparator

I have a comparator like this:

```
lazy val seq = mapping.toSeq.sortWith { case ((_, set1), (_, set2)) =>
  // Just propose all the most connected nodes first to the users
  // But also allow less connected nodes to pop out sometimes
  val popOutChance = random.nextDouble <= 0.1D && set2.size > 5
  if (popOutChance) set1.size < set2.size else set1.size > set2.size
}
```

It is my intention to compare sets sizes such that smaller sets may appear higher in a sorted list with 10% chance.

But compiler does not let me do that and throws an Exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!` once I try to use it in runtime. How can I override it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem here is that, every time two elements are compared, the outcome is random, thus violating the *transitive* property required of a comparator function in any sorting algorithm.

For example, let's say that some instance `a` compares as *less than* `b`, and then `b` compares as less than `c`. These results should imply that `a` compares as less than `c`. However, since your comparisons are *stochastic*, you can't guarantee that outcome. In fact, you can't even guarantee that `a` will be less than `b` next time they're compared.

So don't do that. No sort algorithm can handle it. (Such an approach also violates the *referential transparency* principle of *functional programming* and will make your program much harder to reason about.)

Instead, what you need to do is to decorate your map's members with a randomly assigned weighting - before attempting to sort them - so that they can be sorted consistently. However, since this happens at the start of a sort operation, the result of the sort will be different each time, which I think is what you're looking for.

It's not clear what type `mapping` has in your example, but it appears to be something like: `Map[Any, Set[_]]`. (You can replace the types as required - it's not that important to this approach. For example, say `mapping` actually has the type `Map[String, Set[SomeClass]]`, then you would replace references below to `Any` with `String` and `Set[_]` to `Set[SomeClass]`.)

First, we'll create a `case class` that we'll use to score and compare the map elements. Then we'll map the contents of `mapping` to a sequence of elements of this case class. Next, we sort those elements. Finally, we extract the tuple from the decorated class. The result should look something like this:

```
final case class Decorated(x: (Any, Set[_]), rand: Double = random.nextDouble)
extends Ordered[Decorated] {

  // Calculate a rank for this element. You'll need to change this to suit your precise
  // requirements. Here, if rand is less than 0.1 (a 10% chance), I'm adding 5 to the size;
  // otherwise, I'll report the actual size. This allows transitive comparisons, since
  // rand doesn't change once defined. Values are negated so bigger sets come to the fore
  // when sorted.
  private def rank: Int = {
    if(rand < 0.1) -(x._2.size + 5)
    else -x._2.size
  }

  // Compare this element with another, by their ranks.
  override def compare(that: Decorated): Int = rank.compare(that.rank)
}

// Now sort your mapping elements as follows and convert back to tuples.
lazy val seq = mapping.map(x => Decorated(x)).toSeq.sorted.map(_.x)
```

This should put the elements with larger sets towards the front, but there's 10% chance that sets appear 5 bigger and so move up the list. The result will be different each time the last line is re-executed, since `map` will create new random values for each element. However, during sorting, the ranks will be fixed and will not change.

(Note that I'm setting the rank to a negative value. The `Ordered[T]` trait sorts elements in ascending order, so that - if we sorted purely by set size - smaller sets would come before larger sets. By negating the rank value, sorting will put larger sets before smaller sets. If you don't want this behavior, remove the negations.)

Comment: Thanks for a very elaborate answer! I'll wait 2 days and assign you a bounty.

Comment: @Anton Cheers! Glad you found it useful!